# Very slow rendering in Rails after startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nginx

I am running nginx with rails on a small production server to which I submit several jobs per second, each of which return a json result that I have obtained using `render json: my_result`.

Every time I do a capistrano deployment to production I get very long (5-10 seconds, sometimes more) delay in the rendering step. Once several minutes have passed all this slowness is over.

I tried looking online whether Rails needs to "purge" any previous data that remains in memory due to capistrano having restarted it, but could not find anything, neither how to avoid this issue.

Comment: Do you use Unicorn, passenger, anything else? What is your configuration? Do you preload application master process before spawning the workers? How exactly do you restart with Capistrano?

Comment: @Anatoly, I use a standard configuration: Puma-Rails frontend with Capistrano deployment. I am not sure whether I am preloading application master, where do I set it up? Puma is setup as a service using Foreman and restarted with standard service restart

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing, but I use passenger, every restart it takes a few seconds for it to get itself set.  I just kinda excepted the fact that it take a few seconds. but I do see your point it is a nuisance when you are trying to make simple changes quickly to get things the way you need it.

Comment: Thanks @failpractice for your comment. I wish there was some setting to force rails to get quickly on its feet.

Comment: Hey I just received an answer on the slow issue that may help.  I was recommended to make sure that the app isn't running in Development mode because it will "brutally slow down transfers" hope this helps